# Add S3 Bucket as a network drive

Tags: amazon-s3, network-share

I'm using windows and I need to add my s3 buckets as a network drive on my system. I've found 3 applications: webdrive, tntdrive and gladient. I want to know the idea behind doing this so I could do it myself. Because first, they are not free and second, I need an application with possibility of running from command line.

Answer (score 3):

To mount an S3 filebucket as a network drive, you'd need a filesystem driver that supports it. I'm not aware of any such driver for Windows that's native. Unless you find some application that comes bundled with the driver ([AWS forum link to this topic)](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=344251), you're down to writing one.

Comment: So you are saying all those three applications have their own driver?

Comment: @AliBZ Yes, they must install their own driver software to function.

Comment: Could you give me some tips on where and how to start implementing this?

Comment: That's **way** more than a single Q&A question. Start here: https://www.google.com/search?q=writing+windows+filesystem+driver